# Closing and Opening Twitter Bootstrap Modals Quickly Causing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I have a model open and when I close it and open it very quickly I am seeing a really very odd behavior like backdrop is not disappearing and modal is not showing.

My code is as follows

```
//Opening and Closing Modals

$("#modal").modal("show");
$("#modal").modal("hide");
$("#modal").modal("show");
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qk86/2/).

Comment: show/hide are a sync. They return to the caller before the actual showing/hiding has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should only hide the modal when it is completely shown.

shown.bs.modal

This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Review the modal events here

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```